I have a ticket on Wizz Air with the service Wizz Flex. If I check-in and can I cancel anyway? Or I can cancel it only without checkin?
I have a ticket in wizz air with the service Wizz Flex. If I check-in, can I cancel anyway? Or I can cancel it only without checkin?

The full conditions are available online. Doesn't seem to be anything about check-in. Although knowing Wizz's reputation I wouldn't take anything for granted.

While they don’t mention check-in, note that one must cancel at least 3 hours before scheduled departure time and that they give you a credit valid 90 days, not an actual refund.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That’s why I’m confused, because there is no info about checkin. So I wonder can I checkin but in case I can’t go - cancel 3 hours before the flight…?

Wizz's Terms and Conditions contain this text regarding cancellation:

2. Reservation cancellation and refund request
If you have purchased WIZZ Flex (as standalone service or as part of WIZZ Plus bundle), you can cancel your booking according to the below:
a. In case of one-way flight bookings:
The reservation shall be cancelled no later than 3 hours before the scheduled departure of the flight.
b In case of return flight bookings (including an outbound and an inbound flight):
The cancellation can be done for the full booking or each flight separately no later than 3 hours before the scheduled departure time of the outbound flight (in case of two-leg cancellation) or inbound flight (in case of return flight cancellation).

No mention is made that checking-in (or not) is a requirement for cancellation.
The only stated requirement for cancellation is that the traveler must cancel a one-way flight at least three hours before scheduled departure, and may cancel either or  both legs of a return booking (two flight, one outbound and one inbound), provided the cancelation request is made at least three hours before scheduled departure of the leg(s) to be canceled.
Thus, you appear to be on firm ground to cancel your reservation, checked-in or not, subject only to the minimum three-hour notice period applicable to each flight to be canceled.
However, it's worth noting that airlines generally, and particularly low-cost carriers like Wizz Air, often delay and obfuscate and refuse to make refunds or take other actions required even by the airline's own Terms and Conditions.  You should be prepared for lack of acknowledgment or refusal.

Worth noting that it’s not a refund. It’s a credit valid 90 days.

Thank you for your answer ❤️❤️❤️
